# Extracting sentenses belongs to different category from text using NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I am new to Natural Language Processing (NLP) and I came across a problem where from the given text, I have to extract sentences belongs to different category like

1) sentences related to commitments (like sentences including 'will', 'shall' etc)

2) sentences related to cost or budget

3) and so on....

I need to know which features of NLTK should I use to implement this. How easy to add more and more category to extract more subjective information?

Any examples are even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for text classification and NLTK by itself is not enough. NLTK can do tokenization, stemming, word count, etc. but not classification.

An alternate library in Python is Spacy which will do the above plus allow you to train and use a text classifier to identify sentences that belong to certain category. Suggest you go through the use cases at: [Spacy Usage Examples](https://spacy.io/usage/examples)

For identifying sentences with commitment, you can do a sentence dependency parse and look for "will", "shall" as the verb.